# Fuzzy regex matching with python returns empty list

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy, pypi-regex

I have made a clumsy first attempt at fuzzy pattern matching using the `re` module in python 2.7.

Unfortunately every attempt I make returns an empty list. I simply don't understand the syntax required. I was wondering if someone might tell me why the following code:

```
import re
m = re.findall('(ATCT){e<=1}', 'ATCGATCGGCATGCAGTGCAGAAGTGACGAT')
print m
```

returns an empty list?

Comment: What's ur expected output?

Comment: Are you only interested in the explanation? Not in a solution? Your regex is a mess. It matches `ATCT` followed with `{e<=1}` - these are literal character sequences. See [what it matches](https://regex101.com/r/dR7sK9/1).

Comment: @AvinashRaj the pattern should match to several places in the string with one match, the output should be a list of those patterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am interested in both.

Comment: If you are interested in a solution, please explain - illustrate - what you need to obtain.

Comment: From my understanding, the code above should return a list ['ATCG', 'ATCG']. Clearly my understanding is incorrect so I am interested in what is wrong with the code as is, and in obtaining resources where I might read how to formulate this type of regex search.

Comment: @poppyseeds: I wonder why you expect `ATCG` match when you use  `ATCT` in the pattern? See https://regex101.com/r/dR7sK9/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I expect this as I am attempting to implement fuzzy matching, as opposed to exact matching. The code should allow one error as specified by the {e<=1} which should not be read literally, as detailed here : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2014.10.09

Comment: Yes, `regex`, not `re`. Then, why did you `import re` and not `regex`? See `>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.findall('(ATCT){e<=1}', 'ATCGATCGGCATGCAGTGCAGAAGTGACGAT')
>>> print(m)
['ATCG', 'ATCG']
>>> ` It works as you expect! I guess the question should be closed due to a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you intended to use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2014.10.09), you need to use

```
>>> import regex
>>> m = regex.findall('(ATCT){e<=1}', 'ATCGATCGGCATGCAGTGCAGAAGTGACGAT')
>>> print(m)
['ATCG', 'ATCG']
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not realise they were different modules as I was unaware of the difference. As a follow up question, is there a way to perform this using the re module?

Comment: There is no way to do that with the `re` module.